# How to Use a different model than Users with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a rails application that creates a campaign that collects users emails and their IP. When this occurs, the information is used to create a User.

However I need another user that can sign up and create an account to create and manage this campaign. I'm not exactly sure how to differentiate between the two as I am used to using only one User model.

Below is the way its currently set up:

Routes:

```
Name::Application.routes.draw do

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  root :to => "users#new"

  post 'users/create' => 'users#create'
  get 'refer-a-friend' => 'users#refer'
  get 'privacy-policy' => 'users#policy'

  unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
    get '*not_found', to: 'users#redirect', :format => false
  end
end
```

Schema:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130312045541) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
    t.string   "resource_type", null: false
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_type"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "namespace"
  end

  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id", using: :btree
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace", using: :btree
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "admin_users", ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "admin_users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "delayed_jobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "priority",   default: 0
    t.integer  "attempts",   default: 0
    t.text     "handler"
    t.text     "last_error"
    t.datetime "run_at"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "failed_at"
    t.string   "locked_by"
    t.string   "queue"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
  end

  add_index "delayed_jobs", ["priority", "run_at"], name: "delayed_jobs_priority", using: :btree

  create_table "ip_addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "address"
    t.integer  "count"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "referral_code"
    t.integer  "referrer_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
  end

end
```

Let me know if more information is needed and I'll gladly update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create any number of devise models. Just the names of helper functions change like if you do

```
rails generate devise User
```

then helper functions will be

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
current_user
user_signed_in?
```

But if you do

```
rails generate devise Admin
```

then helper functions will be

```
before_action :authenticate_admin!
current_admin
admin_signed_in?
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing/needing to do. Will update if this turns out to not be the case. Marking correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is on need to have different user model, you can have role in user modal to differentiate campaign, client and admin user.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know that the User model is being used by Devise. I found that if I do "rails g devise somemodelname" then I get a new model that seems to work. Maybe someone knows whether this is incorrect/correct practice?

Comment: Yes, `rails generate devise MODEL` can be used to create new user modal having devise. but  in your code 'admin_users' has devise enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to have a functionality of devise in both models - it looks like you need a double devise. Since your regular `User` and `AdminUser` are totally different you can not really use STI (single table inheritance) or plain `role` attribute on the model. Basically, double devise means you can login into both accounts even simultaneously.

If you just need to have a different devise model, then refer to the docs:
http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/#configuring-models

Simply run

`rails generate devise AdminUser`

and it will do the job for you. To get the instance of current user in controller use `current_admin_user` instead of `current_user` (works with other methods too, such as `user_session` -> `admin_user_session`)